# Is it possible to use a replacement kernel without hacking core?

Tags: 8

I'd like to use a replacement `DrupalKernel`.

It looks like the default is hardcoded into index.php, despite the existence of `DrupalKernelInterface`:

```
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
```

I suspect the answer has to be no, but I thought I'd ask anyway: is it possible to use a custom kernel class without hacking index.php?

Comment: IIRC, there is an issue about this.  I think I even worked on it?

Comment: Right now, it is not possible. Is this a theoretical question or can you actually think of a use case to do this?

Comment: FWIW, this is the issue I was thinking about, https://www.drupal.org/node/2389811  To expand on what @Berdir mentioned, the DrupalKernel derives from the Symfony HttpKernelInterface, which is stackable, so you can add in just about any request/response related functionality you need using your own middleware.

Comment: The DrupalKernel class is a service in the container, you can override the service using the CompilePass way.
Check this https://github.com/hechoendrupal/redis-routing maybe can help you. the problem is when used in static way, you would have to change each of these files.

Comment: Do you have an example @dmouse? The use of `DrupalKernel` is hardcoded into the 5th(ish) line of index.php, which serves every request to a D8 site. How will a compiler pass help with that? Is index.php written on-the-fly or something?

Comment: @MPD Cheers for the info. Not sure how I can use middleware to override a method on `DrupalKernel`, am I missing something there?

Comment: @Berdir It started out real-world (wanted to override the namespace registration method, I'm sure you can guess why from the question yesterday), but I found a better way for that. So it's theoretical now. I know what I've asked isn't physically possible without altering index.php, so I guess now I'm wondering what the options are for doing this as cleanly as possible (again theoretically)

Comment: Sorry @Clive I don't have any example about DrupalKernel, Maybe you can create a new index and use your own class, but the real problem is for example bootstrap.inc, utility.inc and any other file that used this static class. The middleware don't can override services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the classes that implement [`DrupalKernelInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernelInterface.php/interface/DrupalKernelInterface/9.3.x) are:

- [`InstallerKernel`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Installer%21InstallerKernel.php/class/InstallerKernel/9.3.x)
- [`TestKernel`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Test%21TestKernel.php/class/TestKernel/9.3.x)
- [`TestRunnnerKernel`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Test%21TestRunnerKernel.php/class/TestRunnerKernel/9.3.x)

Those classes give you an idea of what they can be used for: If you have a very unusual request flow, which should be much more rare than in Drupal 7, you can write a special kernel.